# ImageView fit width, start from top

Tags: android, imageview, resize

I have an image want it to fit width, but since it's long, I need to keep topmost part visible, I tried using ImageView :

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@mipmap/day_length_background"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    />
```

But result is :

[image]

I can't use fitXY, because it changes aspect ratio.

I need it to be like this
[image]

Comment: Try to set it as background to imageView. It not work can you provide a link to the actual image you are using .

Answer (score 4):

You can use this implementation of TopCropImageView:

```
class TopCropImageView : AppCompatImageView {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        init()
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
        init()
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
        init()
    }

    override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom)
        recomputeImgMatrix()
    }

    override fun setFrame(l: Int, t: Int, r: Int, b: Int): Boolean {
        recomputeImgMatrix()
        return super.setFrame(l, t, r, b)
    }

    private fun init() {
        scaleType = ScaleType.MATRIX
    }

    private fun recomputeImgMatrix() {
        val drawable = drawable ?: return
        val matrix = imageMatrix
        val scale: Float
        val viewWidth = width - paddingLeft - paddingRight
        val viewHeight = height - paddingTop - paddingBottom
        val drawableWidth = drawable.intrinsicWidth
        val drawableHeight = drawable.intrinsicHeight
        scale = if (drawableWidth * viewHeight > drawableHeight * viewWidth) {
            viewHeight.toFloat() / drawableHeight.toFloat()
        } else {
            viewWidth.toFloat() / drawableWidth.toFloat()
        }
        matrix.setScale(scale, scale)
        imageMatrix = matrix
    }
}
```

Top will get aligned and view will get cropped at bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Try `scaleType="fitStart"`

> Scale the image using Matrix.ScaleToFit.START
>
> Matrix.ScaleToFit.START: Compute a scale that will maintain the
>   original src aspect ratio, but will also ensure that src fits entirely
>   inside dst. At least one axis (X or Y) will fit exactly. START aligns
>   the result to the left and top edges of dst.

Reference here: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide#fit_start

Comment: fitStart won't work, because height of image is bigger than screen height, so it fits height instead of width :|

Answer (score 0):

Put your image to your **drawable** folder, and put the image to your layout background i.e

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/image">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also cut your view in half
[image]

or maybe use a custom matrix in java

```
if (imageView.getScaleType() != ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX) {
                    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
                }
                Matrix m = imageView.getImageMatrix();
                int dw = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
                int dh = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
                int msWidth, msHeight;
                float scalew, scaleh;

                Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                Point size = new Point();
                display.getSize(size);
                msWidth = size.x;
                if (imageView.getLayoutParams().width == ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) {
                    msWidth = dw < msWidth ? dw : msWidth;
                }
                scalew = (float) msWidth / dw;
                msHeight = size.y;
                if (imageView.getLayoutParams().height == ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) {
                    msHeight = dh < msHeight ? dh : msHeight;
                }
                scaleh = (float) msHeight / dh;
                float scale = Math.max(scalew, scaleh);

                m.setScale(scale, scale);
                m.postTranslate(0, 0);
                imageView.setImageMatrix(m);
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

centercrop is your problem. Try fitXY, it should work if the aspect ratio is roughly the same.

Comment: No, fitXY corrupts aspect ratio.

Comment: can go through the things I'd try. if you just need the width to match phone, maybe change height to wrap_content. Might have to put it in a scrollview if you want to keep aspect ratio and match width to screen if the image would therefore have to be longer than the screen.